# Invalidate session cookie on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, authentication, cookies

How to delete/invalidate session cookie on the server side so it would be not possible to log in with the stolen cookie?

This is my login code:

```
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Forms"));

var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(claimsPrincipal);
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);

HttpContext.Current.User = claimsPrincipal;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
```

This is my logout code:

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();

HttpContext.Current.User = null;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a time based claim which can be validated on server between two requests along with request validation token provided after authentication and stored in memory or hidden field.